# JQuery datepicker set defaultvalue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use [this date picker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker). I need input to be empty on page loading, but set default value to today on datepicke popap. Now when I jast write:

```
$(".dp").datepicker({
                format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                startDate: '01.01.2012',
                endDate: ''
});;
```

It's first Janary 1970 by default when datapicker is popuping. How can I change default value?

Comment: Since it's not an option for that plugin, and getting it to work would require some sort of hack, why not use the jQuery UI datepicker that does have this as an option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it from the `show` event, but I have to say that datepicker's documentation is really lacking. Here's how:

```
(function() {

  $(".dp").datepicker({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    startDate: '01.01.2012',
    endDate: ''
  }).on("show", function() {
    $(this).val("01.05.2012").datepicker('update');
  });

})();
```

Naturally, where I have `01.05.2012`, put the actual date.

Comment: @knocte: It works just fine. If you'd looked in the console running the live example, you'd've seen it's just that in the year since the example was created, the bootstrap links had rotted. I've updated them now.

Comment: @Walllzzz: Live links just rotted is all, feel free to edit in an update to them. I've removed the live example since it wasn't really necessary and kept rotting.

Answer (score 9):

quick but works

```
  var myDate = new Date();
  var date = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0'+ myDate.getMonth()+1).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0'+ myDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
  $("#datepicker").val(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this, where they want the default value in the input value to show as well as initialize datetimepicker, this works for me. I set the value in the html to data-val and check for that in the ready function. Then, I use moment to covert the string and set the initial picker value:

```
$(function(){
  if($('#complianceBy').data('val').length){
  $('#complianceBy').data('DateTimePicker').date(moment($('#complianceBy').data('val')));
 }
});
```

Answer (score -4):

In bootstrap-datepicker.js (~ Line 331) change:

```
date = new Date(1971, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
```

to

```
date = new Date(),
```

Comment: You should be really cautious editing in a library when there is a cleaner way to get the behavior from the outside (see accepted answer).

Comment: This is a very dangerous way since you're modifying the frameworks itself