# How to set default "Select" option in three date dropdowns(for year, month and day) in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

I'm using three individual dropdowns(three HTML select controls) on my website for the purpose of taking user's date of birth. For this thing to work I've used one jquery library titled **jquery.dateLists.min.js**. I'm using **jquery-1.9.1.min.js** and **jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js**.

Now what's my issue is when the page loads the date dropdown has the current date value selected,the moth dropdowm has the current month selected and the year dropdown has the first year among the years contained(currently it's 1914) in it selected. I want to set the item "Select" with value "" as default selected value. How should I achieve this? For your reference I'm putting below the library code as well as the HTML implementation of it.

**jquery.dateLists.min.js**

```
/*
 * jQuery dateDropDowns
 *
 * url      http://www.amdonnelly.co.uk/jquery/date-drop-down-lists
 * author   Alan Donnelly 2011
 * version  1.0.1
 * license  MIT and GPL licenses
 */
(function(a){a.fn.dateDropDowns=function(k){var g={dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",monthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],yearStart:"1914",yearEnd:"2000"},k=a.extend(g,k);return this.each(function(){function l(){var c=d.getMonth()+1,p="",f=1;_daysInMonth=m(c,d.getFullYear())+1;a("#"+e+"_list").children().length<_daysInMonth?f=a("#"+e+"_list").children().length+1:a("#"+e+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=f;_x<_daysInMonth;_x++)c=d.getDate()==_x?"selected='true'": "",p+="<option value='"+_x+"' "+c+">"+_x+"</option>";a("#"+e+"_list").append(p)}function m(c,a){var d=31;c==4||c==6||c==9||c==11?d=30:c==2&&(d=a%4==0?29:28);return d}function n(){var c=d.getDate(),a=d.getMonth()+1,f=d.getFullYear(),b=g.dateFormat;b.indexOf("DD")>-1&&c.toString().length<2&&(c="0"+c);b.indexOf("MM")>-1&&a.toString().length<2&&(a="0"+a);b=g.dateFormat.toLowerCase();b=b.replace("dd",c);b=b.replace("mm",a);b=b.replace("yy",f);j.val(b)}var j=a(this);j.html();var b=j.attr("id")+"_dateLists", e=b+"_day",h=b+"_month",i=b+"_year",k=j.val(),d=new Date,o=g.dateFormat.indexOf("/")>-1?"/":"-";(function(){if(k.length>0){var a=g.dateFormat.split(o),b=k.split(o),f=new Date;for(_x=0;_x<b.length;_x++)a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("d")>-1?f.setDate(b[_x]):a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("m")>-1?f.setMonth(b[_x]-1):a[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("y")>-1&&f.setYear(b[_x]);d=f}})();(function(){var c=g.dateFormat.split(o),d=j;j.replaceWith("<div id='"+b+"' class='dateLists_container'></div>");for(_x=0;_x<c.length;_x++)c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("d")> -1?(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+e+"' class='day_container'>"),a("#"+e).append("<select id='"+e+"_list' name='"+e+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>")):c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("m")>-1?(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+h+"' class='month_container'>"),a("#"+h).append("<select id='"+h+"_list' name='"+h+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>")):c[_x].toLowerCase().indexOf("y")>-1&&(a("#"+b).append("<div id='"+i+"' class='year_container'>"),a("#"+i).append("<select id='"+ i+"_list' name='"+i+"_list' class='list'></select>"),a("#"+b).append("</div>"));a("#"+b).append(d);j.hide()})();l();(function(){a("#"+h+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=0;_x<12;_x++){var c=d.getMonth()==_x?"selected='true'":"";a("#"+h+"_list").append("<option value='"+_x+"' "+c+">"+g.monthNames[_x]+"</option>")}})();(function(){a("#"+i+"_list").children().remove();for(_x=parseInt(g.yearStart);_x<parseInt(g.yearEnd)+1;_x++){var c=d.getFullYear()==_x?"selected='true'":"";a("#"+i+"_list").append("<option value='"+ _x+"' "+c+">"+_x+"</option>")}})();(function(){a("#"+e+"_list").change(function(){d.setDate(a("#"+e+"_list").val());n()});a("#"+h+"_list").change(function(){var c=parseInt(a("#"+h+"_list").val()),b=d.getDate();_daysInMonth=m(c+1,d.getFullYear());b>_daysInMonth&&(b=_daysInMonth);d=new Date(d.getFullYear(),c,b,0,0,0,0);l();n()});a("#"+i+"_list").change(function(){var b=a("#"+i+"_list").val(),e=d.getDate(),f=d.getMonth();_daysInMonth=m(f+1,b);e>_daysInMonth&&(e=_daysInMonth);d=new Date(b,f,e,0,0,0,0); l();n()})})()})}})(jQuery);
```

The implementation is as follows(All the necessary above said jQuery libraries have been included.)

```
<script language="javascript">
/*The jQuery code to work the functionality*/
$().ready(function() {  
  $('#dob').dateDropDowns({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});  
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

  .dateLists_container {
  }

  .dateLists_container .list {
    float:left;
  }

  .dateLists_container .day_container {

  }

  .dateLists_container .day_container .list {
    margin-right:10px;
  }

  .dateLists_container .month_container {
  }

  .dateLists_container .month_container .list {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
  }

  .dateLists_container .year_container{

  }

  .dateLists_container .year_container .list{

  }

</style>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Date of Birth<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input class="form-control date_control" type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to check the functionality demo it is available at following URL :

```
http://www.amdonnelly.co.uk/jquery/date-drop-down-lists
```

Can some one please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just show us the relevant code, we really don't need the `css` and the plugin source pasted here. Show us your code ? Perhaps prepare a fiddle so we can see the issue.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov:I've added the jQuery code responsible to make the datepicker work. The only intention behind giving you the library code is everything they have achieved like setting months, year range, dates, validations, etc. through this file only. I gone through the file but not able to set "Select" option by default. And without using the CSS you will not be able to show the drop downs. It will be simply a input field if css is excluded.

Comment: Have you tried this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400934/jquery-datepicker-set-defaultvalue

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
    $('#listid').prepend("<option>Select</option>");
    $('#listid').prop("selected", true);
```

This will add a new option to the start of the list and select it, however it will break the plugin.

If you're still trying to use it, I fished out the old source code and uploaded it https://github.com/amdonnelly/jQuery-Date-List-Plugin

If I get time I'll try and add an option for default messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
         $("#sub2sub").append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");

    var drop = $("#sub2cate");
    drop[0].selectedIndex = 0;
<tr>

                        <td>
                            <select id="sub2sub" style="width: 144px;">

                            </select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Javascript to get current date and set it to the option values when page gets load and make them to 'selected' in OPTION.

Try this

```
   var current_date = new Date();
   var dd = current_date.getDate(); // day
   var MM = current_date.getMonth(); // month
   var yyyy = current_date.getFullYear(); //year
```

Comment: :You didn't got my point friend. I don't want to show the current date as default date. I want to show the "Select" value as by defalut for all the three dropdowns.

Comment: To set the values to default you can use <option selected='selected' value=''>

Comment: :But for make it default selected it should be present already in select control which is not in my case. Then how could I set the default value to "Select"?

Comment: try appending the <option selected='selected' >Select</option>

Comment: @Sweetz:But how? Can you please show me how to append?

Comment: provide me the fiddle please