# how to run a default query before submitting a post data in php

Tags: php, mysql

i was trying to display a list of data from a table using date picker, i know using datepicker will display data only after selecting a date, but i want to display data with current date before selecting a date,

```
    include_once "dbcon.php"; 
// Check connection

if(isset ($_POST))
{
    $date=$_POST["crdate"];
if(!$link)
       {
           die('not connected');
       }
            $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate ='".$date."'");
}
```

the above code works well but only after selecting a date, but how to run a default query before selecting a date?

Comment: [link] https://pastebin.com/n7yXnmUh     see this link for complete code..

Comment: Are you using jquerys datepicker? i think this guy already answered it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400934/jquery-datepicker-set-defaultvalue

Comment: if !isset($_POST){ $date =date(Y-m-d); }

Comment: i am using bootstrap datepicker, and the datepicker was working fine and i was managed to fetch data using it, but i was trying to fetch data on page load, i want to display current dated data showed up first before selecting a date using datepicker ......

Comment: make a ajax call to load data from database and store it in global variable then you can use it for further use.

Comment: your using ajax or simple form submit ?

Comment: not ajax, simple form submit....

Comment: submitting the form self page or different page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
if(isset ($_POST))       
{
    if($_POST["crdate"]!="")
    {
        $date=$_POST["crdate"];
    }
    else
    {
        $date=date('Y-m-d');
    }
    if(!$link)
    {
       die('not connected');
    }  
    $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate ='".$date."'");
}
```

Comment: done voting brother.. i was under 15 reputation thats why the vot wasnt showed up publicly ...

Answer (score 1):

just use `else part`  `set $date` is `date('Y-m-d');`

```
    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST["crdate"]!="")
    {
        $date=$_POST["crdate"];

    }
    else
    {
        $date=date('Y-m-d');
    }

    mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate ='".$date."'");
```

**Warning**

> $link   your overwriting the connection variable .$link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate ='".$date."'");

Comment: not working means is there any error ? @MuraleeDharanSugumar

Comment: no error was logged, but the data was not fetched by default and even after post data...

Comment: did you notice that your overwriting the $link connection variable . @MuraleeDharanSugumar

Comment: if(isset ($_POST))       
{
    if($_POST["crdate"]!="")
    {
        $date=$_POST["crdate"];
    }
    else
    {
        $date=date('Y-m-d');
    }
    if(!$link)
    {
       die('not connected');
    }  
    $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate ='".$date."'");
}          @Waseem Ahmad, worked well..